# Indexing elements of parameters of a function within nested for loops

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have two matrices of results, `A = 128x631` and `B = 128x1014` and I have a function `SSD` that takes two elements (x,y) as parameters and then calculates the sum of squared differences. I also have a 631x1014 matrix of 0s, called `SSDMatrix`, ready to put the results of my SSD function into.

What I'm trying to do is compare each element of A with each element of B by passing them into `SSD`, but I can't figure out how to structure my for loops to get the desired results.

When I try:

```
SSDMatrix = SSD(A, B);
```

I get exactly the result I'm looking for, but only for the first cell. How can I repeat this process for each element of `A` and `B`?

Currently I have this:

```
SSDMatrix = zeros(NumFeatures1,NumFeatures2);

for i = 1:631
    for j = 1:1014
        SSDMatrix(i,j) = SSD(A,B);
    end
end
```

This just results in the first answer being repeated 631*1014 times, so I need a way to index A and B to get the appropriate answer for each (i,j) of SSDMatrix.

Comment: So, what must be the size of the output array? `128 x 631 x 128 x 1014`?

Comment: @Divakar it must be 631 x 1014

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you were needed to do something like this -

```
SSDMatrix = zeros(NumFeatures1,NumFeatures2);    
for i = 1:631
    for j = 1:1014
        SSDMatrix(i,j) = sum( (A(:,i) - B(:,j)).^ 2 );
    end
end
```

This, you can achieve with [`pdist2`](http://in.mathworks.com/help/stats/pdist2.html) as well that gets us the square root of summed squared distances. Now, please do note that `pdist2` is part of the `Statistics Toolbox`. So, to get the desired output, you can do -

```
out = pdist2(A.',B.').^2;
```

Or with [`bsxfun`](http://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html) -

```
out = squeeze(sum(bsxfun(@minus,A,permute(B,[1 3 2])).^2,1));
```